# How to keep the value of this when using async.apply?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, async.js

I am using async.parallel to run 2 functions at once, which are run from a static function on a mongoose model. As you can see, I can this `this` to access the model and it's functions in this code (the model has a static function called verifyParent):

```
async.parallel([
      async.apply(content, {slug: slug}),
      async.apply(this.verifyParent, req.body.reply),
    ], (err, result) => {
          //results
});
```

But in the this.verifyParent function, if I try to use `this`, it's equal to my express app, and not the mongoose model. I beleive async.apply is doing this, and I can't figure out how to make it keep the `this` value it would normally have.

In verifyParent, I'm trying to query mongodb. When I run `this.findOne()`, it says it's not a function, and looking at this seems to indicate it's set the app, not to the model.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, `this` is the model.

then you should change code to

```
var model = this;
var verify = function(reply) {
  model.verifyParent(reply);
};
async.parallel([
  async.apply(content, {slug: slug}),
  async.apply(verify, req.body.reply),
], (err, result) => {
      //results
});
```

Because `this` keyword is context based. See [Function context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) for more.

Comment: Sorry, i edited your answer instead of mine. Removed my edit.

Comment: @nrgwsth I found his problem and let him to explore himself. I feel really _sad_ that he awarded your answer.    ;(     PS: bind() returns a functon, for better coding habbit, it should be extracted to local variable. (which is also what I try to show him)

Answer (score 1):

You can just bind the function to current context like this,

```
async.parallel([
      async.apply(content, {slug: slug}),
      async.apply(this.verifyParent.bind(this), req.body.reply),
    ], (err, result) => {
          //results
});
```

[This](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/e4751178540a3c6e64598b93977481ec599704d2/lib/apply.js#L46) is the function definition of async.apply, which seems like it calls the passed function with passed arguments, that's why `this` gets set to parent scope which is express app.

So basically what is happening is this,

```js
function apply(fn) {
  return fn();
}

var model = {
  prop: "world",
  verifyParent: function () {
    console.log("hello", this.prop)
  }
}

// model context is lost.
apply(model.verifyParent)

// bind to model explicitly.
apply(model.verifyParent.bind(model))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the following ways:

**Using arrow functions:**

```
async.parallel([
      async.apply(content, {slug: slug}),
      async.apply(() => this.verifyParent, req.body.reply),
    ], (err, result) => {
          //results
});
```

**Using hard binding:**

```
...
function boundedVerifyParent() {
   return this.verifyParent.call(this)
}
...
async.apply(this.boundedVerifyParent, req.body.reply),
...
```

**Or using `bind` method:**

```
...
async.apply(this.verifyParent.bind(this), req.body.reply),
...
```